# Express-js can't GET my static files, why?

Tags: node.js, express

I've reduced my code to the simplest express-js app I could make:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express.createServer();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/styles'));
app.listen(3001);
```

My directory look like this:

```
static_file.js
/styles
  default.css
```

Yet when I access `http://localhost:3001/styles/default.css` I get the following error:

```
Cannot GET / styles /
default.css
```

I'm using `express 2.3.3` and `node 0.4.7`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check below link http://only4ututorials.blogspot.com/2017/05/how-to-serve-static-file-in-express-js.html

Answer (score 564, accepted):

Try `http://localhost:3001/default.css`.

To have `/styles` in your request URL, use:

```
app.use("/styles", express.static(__dirname + '/styles'));
```

Look at the examples on [this page](http://expressjs.com/api.html):

```
//Serve static content for the app from the "public" directory in the application directory.

    // GET /style.css etc
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Mount the middleware at "/static" to serve static content only when their request path is prefixed with "/static".

    // GET /static/style.css etc.
    app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: In case of new install you should verify that your express module is properly installed (http://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html) then you should check the path and your directory name like Giacomo said ;)

Comment: always use `path.join` to overcome cross platform directory separator issues. path.join(__dirname, '/')

Comment: I put that at my code, but the browser always redirect to "/static/myjs.js/", that last / give me an error of MIME Type

Comment: Does the mount path make sense in `Express` in `prod` or is it a testing issue for dev? Maybe it looks more ordered to have an url folder.

Comment: If anyone using TypeScript (or not) stumbles upon this comment and has the same problem: if your file is in a `src/` dir, use `path.join(__dirname, "../public")`.

Comment: Shouldn't app.use() without a specified path handle all requests? Then why will `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` not work for /static?

Comment: oh darn, app.get doesn't work, has to be app.use

Answer (score 54):

I have the same problem. I have resolved the problem with following code:

```
app.use('/img',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/images')));
app.use('/js',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/javascripts')));
app.use('/css',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/stylesheets')));
```

Static request example:

```
http://pruebaexpress.lite.c9.io/js/socket.io.js
```

I need a more simple solution. Does it exist?

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution regardless of whether it is optimal or not. If you want to reopen the issue for optimization, consider posting a new question detailing the new circumstances. If optimization is the sole purpose, the question may be better suited to [SO Code Review](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review).

Comment: In my case, the only way to make static imports work with expressjs has been to use the "`path`" module. All other solutions without `path.join` or prepending the `__dirname` string have been fruitless.

Answer (score 23):

This work for me:

```
app.use('*/css',express.static('public/css'));
app.use('*/js',express.static('public/js'));
app.use('*/images',express.static('public/images'));
```

Answer (score 17):

`default.css` should be available at `http://localhost:3001/default.css`

The `styles` in `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/styles'));` just tells express to look in the `styles` directory for a static file to serve. It doesn't (confusingly) then form part of the path it is available on.

Comment: Totally! Which is by convention in express.js you do it on `/public` which has `css`, `js`, `img` folders so you can `http://localhost:3001/css/default.css` :)

Answer (score 12):

In your server.js :

```
var express   =     require("express");
var app       =     express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

You have declared express and app separately, create a folder named 'public' or as you like, and yet you can access to these folder. In your template src, you have added the relative path from /public (or the name of your folder destiny to static files). Beware of the bars on the routes.

Answer (score 10):

I am using Bootstrap CSS, JS and Fonts in my application. I created a folder called `asset` in root directory of the app and place all these folder inside it. Then in server file added following line:

```
app.use("/asset",express.static("asset"));
```

This line enables me to load the files that are in the `asset` directory from the `/asset` path prefix like: `http://localhost:3000/asset/css/bootstrap.min.css`.

Now in the views I can simply include CSS and JS like below:

```
<link href="/asset/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: This is the answer that is well explained that worked for me. +1 for taking the pain to elaborate and give an example that works. Last time this worked for me on a previous project it was just by fluke but today as I work on another new project I understand how it works from the good explanation in your answer.

Answer (score 9):

What worked for me is:

Instead of writing  **`app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public/images'));`** in your app.js

Simply write 
**`app.use(express.static('public/images'));`**

i.e  remove the root directory name in the path. And then you can use the static path effectively in other js files, For example:

```
<img src="/images/misc/background.jpg">
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This solved my issue. In my code, path to CSS was working fine even with the __dirname concatenation (using path.join), while fetching js was failing.

Answer (score 6):

to serve static files (css,images,js files)just two steps:

1. pass the directory of css files to built in middleware express.static

   ```
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();
   /*public is folder in my project directory contains three folders
   css,image,js
   */
   //css  =>folder contains css file
   //image=>folder contains images
   //js   =>folder contains javascript files
   app.use(express.static( 'public/css'));
   ```
2. to access css files or images just type in url http://localhost:port/filename.css ex:http://localhost:8081/bootstrap.css

**note:** to link css files to html just type`<link href="file_name.css" rel="stylesheet">`

if i write this code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/css',express.static( 'public/css'));
```

to access the static files just type in url:localhost:port/css/filename.css
ex:http://localhost:8081/css/bootstrap.css

**note** to link css files with html just add the following line

```
<link href="css/file_name.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 5):

this one worked for me

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/img',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/images')));

app.use('/shopping-cart/javascripts',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/javascripts')));

app.use('/shopping-cart/stylesheets',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/stylesheets')));

app.use('/user/stylesheets',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/stylesheets')));

app.use('/user/javascripts',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/javascripts')));
```

Answer (score 2):

### Webpack makes things awkward

As a supplement to all the other already existing solutions:

First things first: If you base the paths of your files and directories on the `cwd` (current working directory), things should work as usual, as the `cwd` is the folder where you were when you started `node` (or `npm start`, `yarn run` etc).

However...

If you are using webpack, `__dirname` behavior will be very different, depending on your `node.__dirname` settings, and your webpack version:

1. In Webpack v4, the default behavior for `__dirname` is just `/`, as [documented here](https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#node__dirname).

   - In this case, you usually want to add this to your config which makes it act like the default in v5, that is `__filename` and `__dirname` now behave as-is **but** for the output file:

     ```js
     module.exports = {
        // ...
        node: {
          // generate actual output file information
          // see: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#node__filename
          __dirname: false,
          __filename: false,
        }
     };
     ```
   - This has also been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43527016/dirname-is-not-working-in-node-js-with-webpack-bundling).
2. In Webpack v5, [per the documentation here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/), the default is already for `__filename` and `__dirname` to behave as-is **but** for the output file, thereby achieving the same result as the config change for v4.

#### Example

For example, let's say:

- you want to add the static `public` folder
- it is located next to your output (usually `dist`) folder, and you have no sub-folders in `dist`, it's probably going to look like this

```js
const ServerRoot = path.resolve(__dirname /** dist */, '..');
// ...
app.use(express.static(path.join(ServerRoot, 'public'))
```

(**important:** again, this is independent of where your source file is, only looks at where your output files are!)

#### More advanced Webpack scenarios

Things get more complicated if you have multiple entry points in different output directories, as the `__dirname` for the **same** file might be different for output file (that is each file in `entry`), depending on the location of the output file that this source file was merged into, and what's worse, the same source file might be merged into multiple **different** output files.

You probably want to avoid this kind of scenario scenario, or, if you cannot avoid it, use Webpack to manage and infuse the correct paths for you, possibly via the `DefinePlugin` or the `EnvironmentPlugin`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with serving `__dirname` is that `__dirname` returns the path of the current file, not the project's file.
Also, if you use a dynamic header, each page will look for the static files in a different path and it won't work.
The best, for me, is to substitute `__dirname` for `process.cwd()` which ALWAYS donates the path to the project file.

```
app.use(express.static(process.cwd() + '/public'));
```

And in your project:

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/default.css"
```

See: [What's the difference between process.cwd() vs __dirname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874382/whats-the-difference-between-process-cwd-vs-dirname)

Answer (score 2):

I was using

```js
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

When there was no file in the public folder with name `index.html`.

I was getting the following error in the browser:

> "Cannot GET /"

When I renamed the file to 'index.html', it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I find my css file and  add a route to it:

```
app.get('/css/MyCSS.css', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/css/MyCSS.css');
});
```

Then it seems to work.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach as you should be using ExpressJS's `.use()` and `express.static()` methods to send where you are serving your files. Otherwise you'll have one of these router per file in your public directory and that's a lot of overhead to maintain.

Comment: This is a work around but I do not think it is appropriate. If you have many CSS and JS files, how can you maintain it?

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing it with http://localhost:3001/default.css.

```
   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/styles'));
```

You are actually giving it the name of folder i.e. styles not your suburl.

Answer (score 1):

if your setup

```
myApp
  |
  |__ public
  |     |
  |     |__  stylesheets
  |     |     |
  |     |     |__ style.css
  |     |
  |     |___ img
  |           |
  |           |__ logo.png
  |
  |__ app.js
```

then,
put in app.js

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'));
```

and refer to your style.css: (in some .pug file):

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/static/stylesheets/style.css')
```

Comment: Why would you introduce a renaming step public -> static? I would say that is just more confusing extra information. But then again indirection is usually a good thing...

Answer (score 1):

Try `'./public'` instead of `__dirname + '/public'`.
Similarly, try `process.cwd() + '/public'`.

Sometimes we lose track of the directories we are working with, its good to avoid assuming that files are located where we are telling express where they are.

Similarly, avoid assuming that in the depths of dependencies the path is being interpreted the same way at every level.

Comment: 100%. Always try to use `__dirname`, unless you have a case where you don't need to access the project files all the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/'));
```

This worked for me, I tried using a public directory but it didn't work.
But in this case, we give access to the whole static files in the directory, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above, make sure the static file path begins with /  (ex... /assets/css)... to serve static files in any directory above the main directory (/main)

Comment: Addition to what above? State it in your answer (give credit to the person who posted it, if you have to). SO often changes the order of the answers so that all answers get seen and not the the first few. We don't know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a  folder   with    'public'  name in   Nodejs  project
   folder.
2. Put  index.html file into of Nodejs project folder.
3. Put  all    script  and   css   file  into    public 
   folder.
4. Use `app.use( express.static('public'));`
5. and  in  `index.html`      correct   path  of  scripts  to `<script type="text/javascript" src="/javasrc/example.js"></script>`

And  Now all things work fine.

Answer (score 0):

[static directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mp04.png)

**check the above image(static directory) for dir structure**

```
const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname,'../public')
app.use(express.static(publicDirectoryPath))


//  or

app.use("/", express.static(publicDirectoryPath))
app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(publicDirectoryPath,'index.html'))
```

Answer (score 0):

**In your nodejs file**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use('/static', express.static('path_to_static_folder'));
```

**In your pug file**

```
...
script(type="text/javascript", src="static/your_javascript_filename")
...
```

Note the "static" word. It must be same in nodejs file and pug file.

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me:

Server:

```js
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

Client:

```html
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<img src="images/210504.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered (and solved) a variation on this (node v16.16.0).

folder structure:

```
    project
      apidoc
      src
        index.js (aka server.js, app.js)
        public
          images
          css
```

I am serving static content from 'public':

```
    app.use(express.static('src/public'))
```

and wanted to also serve the api docs from apidocs (one folder above the current folder). This wouldn't work:

```
    app.use('/apidoc', express.static('../apidoc')))
    // this didn't work either
    app.use('/apidoc', express.static('/absolute/path/to/apidoc')))
```

This was the solution:

```
    import path from 'path'
    import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
    const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
    const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

    app.use('/apidoc', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../apidoc')))
    app.use(express.static('src/public'))
```

I suspect a path separator issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your folder structure looks like this

```
myApp
  |
  |__ public
  |     |
  |     |__  stylesheets
  |     |     |
  |     |     |__ style.css
  |     |
  |     |___ img
  |           |
  |           |__ logo.png
  |
  |__ src
        |
        |__ app.js
```

use the line below:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.resolve('public')))
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
app.use('/public/',express.static(path.join('./public')));
```

I find this solution after finding it for hours it works for me!!

Answer (score -11):

i just try this code and working

```
const exp = require('express');
const app = exp();

app.use(exp.static("public"));
```

and working,

before (not working) :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

just try

Comment: There's absolutely no change in this, lol

Comment: hehe,, this just work for me before, just share my case and i don't know why its work,