# Why can't I get to my javascript files from Expressjs/Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm starting to experiment with nodejs/expressjs/coffeescript and the jade view engine.

I have the following setup which from what I can see from the examples that are around seems pretty standard.

```
    app = express.createServer().listen process.env.PORT

    app.configure ->
        app.set 'views', __dirname + '/views'
        app.set 'view engine', 'jade'
        app.set 'view options', layout: true
        app.use express.bodyParser()
        app.use express.static(__dirname + '/public')
        app.use app.router


    app.get '/ekmHoliCal/index', (req, res) ->
        res.render 'index'
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
-- ekmHoliCal
  -- public
     --javascripts 
          client.js
  -- views
       index.jade
       layout.jade
```

The index file contains nothing but the the line:
    **This is the index file**

the layout.jade file contains:

```
!!! 5
html(lang="en")
    head
        title Users
        script(type="text/javascript", src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js")
        script(type="text/javascript", src="/ekmholical/javascripts/client.js")
    body 
        div!= body
```

When I navigate to localhost/ekmHoliCal/index I get served the index page as expected. However if I view source I see a link to to jquery :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js">
```

and if I click on that link sure enough I see the source of the jquery file.

The index file source also contains a link to my client.js file as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ekmholical/javascripts/simon.js"></script>
```

but when I click on that I get

**Cannot GET /ekmholical/javascripts/client.js**

I've seen this related question ([Express-js can't GET my static files, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924072/express-js-cant-get-my-static-files-why)) and can't see what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your script tag has the wrong path. it should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/simon.js"></script>
```

In express, you've set the following:

```
app.use express.static(__dirname + '/public')
```

That tells express/node that the `public` directory should act as your web root. Everything in it can be referenced via `/`, so if you also have a CSS folder in there, you might use `/css/styles.css`

Comment: Thanks Paul. I had already tried your suggestion without success. That said, your answer is correct. What I negated to mention was that I'm running this on windows under IIS and it appears to be my configuration of the site under IIS that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Following up on what Paul Armstrong said, you could also do this.

```
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public');
```

This will allow you to reference your js file like this:

```
<script src="/public/javascripts/simon.js"></script>
```

Comment: EXACT : the Express api 4.x say :

**Serve static content for the app from the “public” directory in the application directory**:

// GET /style.css etc
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Otherwise '/ ' is the root of your computer.