# What's the difference between process.cwd() vs __dirname?

Tags: node.js

What's the difference between

```
console.log(process.cwd())
```

and

```
console.log(__dirname);
```

I've seen both used in similar contexts.

Answer (score 674, accepted):

[`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) returns the current working directory,

i.e. the directory from which you invoked the `node` command.

[`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) returns the directory name of the directory containing the JavaScript source code file

Comment: Does this mean that `process.cwd()` is synonym to `.` for all cases except for `require()`?

Comment: @AlexanderGonchiy correct, `.` is relative to `process.cwd()` (so synonymous), except for `require()` which works relative to current executing file. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16730379/927631) for more.

Comment: Note that the current working directory can be changed at runtime using process.chdir, so it is not always the directory from which node was invoked.

Answer (score 164):

As per node js [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd)
`process.cwd()`

`cwd` is a method of global object `process`, returns a string value which is the current working directory of the Node.js process.

As per node js [doc](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname)
`__dirname`

The directory name of current script as a string value. `__dirname` is not actually a global but rather local to each module.

Let me explain with examples:

suppose we have a `main.js` file that resides inside `C:/Project/main.js`
and running `node main.js` both these values return same file.

or simply with the following folder structure

```
Project 
├── main.js
└──lib
   └── script.js
```

`main.js`

```
console.log(process.cwd())
// C:\Project
console.log(__dirname)
// C:\Project
console.log(__dirname === process.cwd())
// true
```

suppose we have another file `script.js` files inside a sub directory of project, i.e. `C:/Project/lib/script.js` and running `node main.js` which require `script.js`

`main.js`

```
require('./lib/script.js')
console.log(process.cwd())
// C:\Project
console.log(__dirname)
// C:\Project
console.log(__dirname === process.cwd())
// true
```

`script.js`

```
console.log(process.cwd())
// C:\Project
console.log(__dirname)
// C:\Project\lib
console.log(__dirname === process.cwd())
// false
```

> Simply it can be stated as:
>
> `process.cwd()` returns the value of directory where we run the node process, whereas
>
> `__dirname` returns the value of directory where the current running file resides.

Answer (score 15):

Knowing the **scope** of each can make things easier to remember.

**`process`** is `node`'s global object, and **`.cwd()`** returns where node is running.

**`__dirname`** is `module`'s property, and represents the file path of the module. In node, one module resides in one file.

Similarly, **`__filename`** is another `module`'s property, which holds the file name of the module.

Answer (score 8):

$ `find proj`

```
proj
proj/src
proj/src/index.js
```

$ `cat proj/src/index.js`

```
console.log("process.cwd() = " + process.cwd());
console.log("__dirname = " + __dirname);
```

$ `cd proj; node src/index.js`

```
process.cwd() = /tmp/proj
__dirname = /tmp/proj/src
```