# Node js/Express js relative paths (dot or __dirname or without any prefix)?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm looking at Nodejs/expressjs and have seen different tutorials use either `__diranme + "/my_folder"`, `"./my_folder"`, or just `"my_folder"`.

Examples:

```
app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname + "/my_folder"));
app.use("/static", express.static("./my_folder"));
app.use("/static", express.static("my_folder"));
```

I tried them all and they all seem to work; which one should I use for relative paths?

I've also seen `require('./my_file.js')` and `require('my_file')`. Is there a difference? What should I use?

Comment: I believe the last way of defining locations will break on Windows.  I'm 90% using `__dirname + '/folder'` is the safest approach (with no concrete evidence, just random experience messing around with node in Windows).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Almost any function (except for `require`) which takes file paths as an argument, will at one point use functions from the `fs` module to read from or write to them.

[Node.js documentation for fs module](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) says:

> Relative path to filename can be used, remember however that this path will be relative to process.cwd().

When you think about it, it would require major trickery to have these functions behave any differently. After all, the fs functions are regular Javascript and they don't have special access to information about the caller. The only `__dirname` they could access would be the `__dirname` of their own module (the core fs module).

The fact that the `require` function *can* resolve paths relative to the current `__dirname`, without specifying this explicitly, is because `require` is a unique function for every single file it appears in. This way, it has access to the current module's specifics, and in particular its path.

The reason your code happens to work is that currently, the `app.js` (or similar) the code above appears in happens to be in the same directory as what `process.cwd()` currently is. I.e. starting the app with `node app.js` would work, while starting the app with `node myappdir/app.js` (ran from its parent directory) would not. `process.cwd()` would be different.

As long as you keep in mind that relative paths will be resolved via `process.cwd()`, then you could use the shorter syntax. In some cases it can be an advantage. It does make your code dependent on how it's called though. I personally prefer using `__dirname`, because it's somewhat more transparent as to what's happening, and the relative paths consistent with the paths you use in a `require` statement for the same file.

Comment: Thanks, very informative. So if I understand: `require` will always be relative to the current file (using `dot` or `__dirname`). All other paths - which probably go through `fs`, can be relative to the process with a `dot`, and relative to the calling-file if passed with `__dirname`

Comment: Exactly. But doing `__dirname + "some path"` is just regular string concatenation. It's a special way of calling a function or so. It results in an absolute path, leaving out any room for interpretation.

Answer (score 9):

The `__dirname` version is the most robust since `__dirname` will always be the directory containing the currently executing `.js` file, which is a better anchor than `"my_folder"` or `"./my_folder"` which are both relative paths and will fail if the process's current working directory (`process.cwd()`) is something unexpected, which is entirely possible.

Note that it's a different story for paths passed to `require`, since relative paths there are resolved relative to the location of the calling module without regard for the process's current working directory (again, this makes them less fragile).

Comment: For require, should I include the extension? Like I often see
`require(__dirname + "/something")` but why not `require(__diranem + "/something.js")` (which seems to work too)?

Comment: Edit: Found `If the exact filename is not found, then node will attempt to load the required filename with the added extension of .js, .json, and then .node.` On the docs (missed it before, found it looking for something else). So now I know how it works, but do you think it's a good habit to be explicit or... implicit (reminds me of python xD )

Comment: The convention is no filename (implicit) and I think that's good. You can also switch from `module.js` to `module/index.js` and programs using your library don't have to care or be updated.

Answer (score 1):

I use `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` which i then have three folders inside of my public, stylesheets, javascripts and images which allows me to access those static files by

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/jquery-ui.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

the `./myfolder` approach I believe is essentially the same thing. I have never used it.
the `/myfolder` approach I have never seen.

```
   require('./my_file.js') I use as 
   require('./routes/my_file.js') aand is where I store all my express routes.
```

The `require('myfile')` is a call to packages that you install or come install with express.