# hubot script load yml file, dont work with relative path

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, filesystems, yaml, hubot

I am building a hubot script and I want to load a yml file in it.
I am using the yamljs npm package to read the YAML file.

The problem is that it allways says "No such file or directory" error.
If i put the absolute path it works.

What I am missing? 
I am loading the file like this:

```
feeds = YAML.load('../feeds.yml');
```

Here is my directory structure:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to load the yml file? If you want to use an environment variable declared in feeds.yml such as (HUBOT_VAR: test), you can access it easily using process.env.HUBOT_VAR. See the Environment Variables section [here](https://github.com/github/hubot/blob/master/docs/scripting.md) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Where are you executing the script from? In node, path files in `fs` are relative to `process.cwd()`.

> Relative path to filename can be used, remember however that this path
>   will be relative to process.cwd().

Sources: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16730379/1007263

Therefore, if your script is in the same directory as `feeds.yml`, you should probably:

```
feeds = YAML.load('./feeds.yml');
```

Otherwise, there might be a bug in YAML. In this case, you can simply use `path` to deliver the absolute path directly.

```
path.resolve('../feeds.yml')
```

Source: http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to