# vuejs webpack relative modules were not found error

Tags: npm, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I have full-stack application with express and default vue-webpack-boilerplate.
My project structure looks like this:

```
├── client
│   ├── build
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── config
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── dist
|   |   └── ...
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── App.vue
│   │   ├── assets
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   ├── components
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   ├── main.js
│   │   └── router
│   └── static
├── node_modules
├── package.json
└── server
    ├── app.js
    ├── bin
    │   └── www
    └── routes
        └── ...
```

When I run `$ node client/build/dev-server.js` i receive this error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors

These relative modules were not found:

* ./build/dev-client in multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js
* ./src/main.js in multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js
```

but only if I trying to run it from client folder it works properly.

```
$ cd client 
$ node build/dev-server.js
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the error with relative paths. You need to change all paths exept those with used in `require()`, relative to the new root folder, not the client folder. Good practice is using of `__dirname` which is same to `path.diranme()` method. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727045/node-js-express-js-relative-paths-dot-or-dirname-or-without-any-prefix).

Comment: This answer is unclear. Can you please post exact solution to the problem ?
what steps did u take to solve it ?

Comment: For me this was solved by adding the following to the webpack config: 
context: __dirname
Depending on your setup you might need something like
context: path.join(__dirname, '../')