# JavaScript - WebDriverIO - How to chooseFile with relative file path to upload?

Tags: javascript, selenium, meteor, webdriver-io

I'm writing tests for my current project using `CucumberJS`. The test will be tested using `Selenium Server + WebDriverIO`. Now I'm stucking at the test where I have to choose an image file to upload to the server. I'm using this WebDriverIO's function:

```
chooseFile(String selector, String localFilePath, Function callback)
Given a selector corresponding to an <input type=file>, will upload the local file to the browser machine and fill the form accordingly. It does not submit the form for you.
```

The thing is that, because I want the test to be runnable in every computer so I pre-uploaded some test image files to the server's `root` folder. Because I don't know where this `root` folder is going to be put in other computers, I think there must be a way to submit a relative file path to the `chooseFile` function. I tried this way but it didn't work (this is the code in my mentioned below file `uploadImg.coffee`)

```
@Given /^user attemp to upload his first avatar$/, (callback) ->
    @browser
    .click ".change-avatar"
    .chooseFile "input[name=avatarFile]", "/imgForTesting/spiderman.png"
    .click "#saveAvatarButton"
    .call callback
    return
```

This is my project folder structure (I'm using `MeteorJS`):

```
public/ (root)
---imgForTesting/
------spiderman.png
packages/
---test-cucumber/
------features/
---------uploadImg.feature
---------step_definitions/
------------uploadImg.coffee
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this node command: `process.cwd()` (http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) which will helps getting the absolute path of the current working directory.

More reading: [What's the difference between process.cwd() vs __dirname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874382/whats-the-difference-between-process-cwd-vs-dirname)