# Resolve relative path relative to another path instead of current working directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node.js module that looks like this:

```
module.exports = function()
{
    // linked dependencies
    this.dependency1 = 'dependency1/dependency1.exe';
    this.dependency2 = 'dependency2/dependency2.exe';
    this.dependency3 = 'dependency3/dependency3.exe';
}
```

I want developers to be able to easily edit the location of the dependencies *relative to the module file itself*. However, when using the module, the current working directory `process.cwd()` is usually not the same as the module directory, so those paths do not resolve correctly. `path.resolve()` only seems to work relative to the current working directory, and doesn't have any arguments to allow for a custom reference point/path.

I have been able to resolve the paths in the following way, but I find it ugly and cumbersome, and it should be easier than this:

```
this.ResolvePath = function(p)
{
    var cwd = process.cwd();
    process.chdir(path.dirname(module.filename));
    var resolvedPath = path.resolve(p);
    process.chdir(cwd);
    return resolvedPath;
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? I feel like `path.relative()` should hold the solution, but I can't find a way to make it work. Perhaps chaining together multiple `path.relative()`s could work, but I can't wrap my brain around how that would work right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why not just:

```
 path.resolve(__dirname, p)
```

`__dirname` [works a bit differently and returns the current modules path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874382/whats-the-difference-between-process-cwd-vs-dirname), which can then be joined easily with the relative path.

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware that `path.resolve()` could be used in that manner

Comment: For people wanting to use `require.resolve` (for its automatic adding/finding of `.js`, `/index.js`, etc.), but just from a different folder than the current file's, see [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#requireresolverequest-options). Example: `let resolvedPath = require.resolve(subPath, {paths: [pathToResolveSubPathFrom]});`