# How do I upload a file at a relative path with Playwright and TS?

Tags: typescript, playwright

I'm trying to upload a file in a Playwright test written in TypeScript.

```
  const fileWithPath = './abc.jpg';
  const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForEvent('filechooser'),
    page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Add a Photo' }).click(),
  ]);
  await fileChooser.setFiles([fileWithPath]);
```

However, this doesn't work; I get an error:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat './abc.jpg'`

If I change the file path to an absolute path it works:

`const fileWithPath = '/Users/private/d/ionic/tests/playwright/optional/abc.jpg';`

However, I develop on macOS and run the automated tests on linux, so I'd really like to commit the image file (abc.jpg) to the same directory as the test and then use a relative path to reference it in an OS-agnostic way.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you not resolve the file's full path with `node:path` and the test file's own location?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Maybe, but I don't know how to do that.  I know nothing about node; I'm just writing Playwright tests.

Comment: So look that up, e.g. "node resolve relative file path" -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/38829118/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/52615764/3001761

Answer (score 0):

Based on a hint from @jonrsharpe and the [file-chooser](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-filechooser) documentation, this is the working solution I came up with:

```
  import * as path from 'path';

  const fileWithPath = path.join(__dirname, 'abc.jpg');
  const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForEvent('filechooser'),
    page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Add a Photo' }).click(),
  ]);
  await fileChooser.setFiles([fileWithPath]);
```