# How to get the base dir to refrain from using ../../../ when requiring modules in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

### My folder structure:

```
-base directory  
--app.js

--models  
---property.js  

--routers  
---api  
----v1
-----properties.js
```

### My Problem

In ***routers/api/v1/properties.js***, how do I do get the base directory so I can stop doing this:

```js
const Property = require('../../../models/property');
```

I want to remove the repetitive ../../../

### My Current Solution

In my ***app.js***, I add a line:

```js
global.__basedir = __dirname;
```

And then in ***routers/api/v1/properties.js***,

```js
const path = require('path');
const Property = require(__basedir + '/models/property');
```

So what do you think? Are there pitfalls to this method? Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: You can use [`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd), assuming that `app.js` is the entry point. See [What's the difference between process.cwd() vs __dirname?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9874382/1541563)

Comment: [How to make node.js require absolute? (instead of relative)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860244/how-to-make-node-js-require-absolute-instead-of-relative/24630974#24630974)

Comment: Also for a cross platform Node.js application, you should avoid concatenating strings to create relative paths, and use `path.join()` or `path.resolve()` from the [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.htm) module depending on your use-case.

Comment: In addition to the ways mentioned above, you can also try [`module.createRequireFromPath(filename)`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_createrequirefrompath_filename) (needs Node.js 10 at least).

Comment: Hi guys! Thanks for the input. I went for process.cwd() since it seems like the most official nodejs thing to do. I am also using path.join now.

Answer (score 2):

**Using a 3rd party module:**

Use `app-root-path` module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-root-path).

```js
const appRoot = require('app-root-path');
const myModule = require(appRoot + '/lib/my-module.js');
```

### Update:

**Using built-in Node functionality**

You can set `NODE_PATH` environment variable to your base directory. Then you should be able to `require` modules relative to the `NODE_PATH` from anywhere in your project.

e.g,

Let's say your file is app.js and has the following content,

```js
const Property = require('models/property');
```

You could run it as follows (replace `/path/to/base/directory` with the path to the base directory):

```
$ NODE_PATH=/path/to/base/directory node app.js
```

You can read more about it in the documentation here: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders

> **It's important** to know that most IDEs don't know/care about the `NODE_PATH` variable (for example VSCode), therefore intellisense will break because IDE doesn't know where it can find the module `models/property`. But it should be fixable using IDE-specific configurations. See here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/28707#issuecomment-308513626

Comment: Thanks! Tried it too but decided to got for process.cwd() instead.

Comment: Yeah. That works too. But it depends on which directory you run your application from obviously. :)

Comment: I updated my answer with a better solution.