# "message": "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\\astrology\\utils\\uploads\\1600798534862qf.png'"

Tags: node.js, express, multer

As the title suggests, I am getting `error: {"message": "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\\astrology\\utils\\uploads\\1600798534862qf.png'"}` in my project even after passing every required configs.

Note: I've divided 'app' into two parts: main 'app.js' and 'appRoute.js' for more dynamic and code clarity.

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
const directory = path.join(__dirname, "utils/uploads");
app.use("/uploads", express.static(directory));

require("./config/database/db")();
require("./config/approutes/appRoutes")(app);

module.exports = app;
```

**appRoute.js**

```
require("dotenv").config();

const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const productRoutes = require("../../api/routes/products");

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(morgan("dev"));

  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: "100mb" }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true }));

  app.use("/products", productRoutes);
  
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const error = new Error("Not found");
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
  });

  app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    console.log('SHOW ERROR', error);
    
    res.status(error.status || 500);
    res.json({
      error: {
        message: error.message,
      },
    });
  });
};
```

**fileUpload.js**

```
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, __dirname + "/uploads");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname.replace(/\s+/g, "-"));
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  // reject a file
  if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype === "image/png") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
  },
  fileFilter: fileFilter,
});

module.exports = upload;
```

**Product.js (controller)**

```
exports.create_product = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { title, min_content, content } = req.body;

  console.log("req files", req.files);

  try {
    const product = new Product({
      title,
      min_content,
      content,
    });

    const new_product = await product.save();
    console.log("error caught", new_product);

    if (new_product) {
      res.status(201).json({ msg: "New product added", new_product });
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({ msg: "Unable to create new product" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ msg: "Internal server error", error });
  }
};
```

**Product.js (route)**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const ProductController = require("../controllers/products");
const uploadMW = require("../middleware/fileUpload");

router.get("/all", ProductController.get_products);
router.post("/new", uploadMW.fields([{ name: "thumbnail" }, { name: "image" }]), ProductController.create_product
);

module.exports = router;
```

**Directory structure**

[image: directory structure]

My OS is windows, so I have included the config to replace the (:) from file names, but nothing seems to work for me. Any help to resolve the same is appreciated.

Comment: did you try setting path to `cb(null, __dirname + "/../uploads");`?

Comment: Where is the `uploads` directory relative to `fileUpload.js`

`cb(null, __dirname + "/uploads");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directory structures look messed up.
Your `uploads` directory in `fileUpload.js`
is referring to a directory in `./api/middleware/uploads` when it should be referencing `./utils/uploads` (the paths relative to the module are incorrect).

```
// fileUpload.js
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, path.resolve(__dirname, `..${path.sep}..${path.sep}`, `${path.sep}utils${path.sep}uploads`);
  },
```

`__dirname` returns the directory that the current file is in. So in this case it will be `middleware`. (I am deducing this based on the require in your `Product.js` file).

Try fixing the path to the `uploads` directory in the `fileUpload.js` by pointing at the same directory that the static files are being served from.

Also, I seen in the chat that `Arya` started with you that you are now managing to get it working on a *nix OS but not on windows.

Try changing your path separators to use `path.sep` from the `path` module. `Arya`'s solution above looks good, i.e. the file paths now all look fixed relative to the static `uploads` directory. I have updated my answer to use path.sep based on the original code that you published and the directory structure that you provided.

Comment: Sorry for looking up late. I have updated my question

Comment: @bubble-cord I updated my answer based on updated directory structure and the fact that it works on *nix but not Windows

Comment: Thanks, your solution did help to resolve the 'EONENT' not found issue, & img is getting upload as seen from postman while testing. But, the img is not yet getting saved to the db.  The file object on console has double \\, which I think causing the problem.  `req file {
  fieldname: 'thumbnail',
  originalname: 'wp1910893.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: 'E:\\utils\\uploads',
  filename: '1601924503515wp1910893.jpg',
  path: 'E:\\utils\\uploads\\1601924503515wp1910893.jpg',
  size: 364652
}`. I am unable to figure out this double \\ behaviour

Comment: No - that is to be expected with Windows paths. Here is a good article on best practices for traversing the filesystem with nodejs https://shapeshed.com/writing-cross-platform-node/

Comment: If the EONENT issue is resolved accept the answer that you believe helped it. Not getting saved to the DB is probably another issue

Answer (score 6):

app.js file will be like this

```
// modules =================================================
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require("path");
config = require("./environments/index");
var http = require('http').Server(app);

// configuration ===========================================
var port = config.PORT || 8081; // set our port

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
limit: '50mb',
extended: true,
parameterLimit: 50000
}));
app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'))
app.use("/api", indexRouter);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/build")));

http.listen(port, () => {
   console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port); // shoutout to the user
});

exports = module.exports = app;
```

create multerhelper.js file in your app nd add below code in it

```
const multer = require('multer');

// const fs = require('fs');
let fs = require('fs-extra');

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
   let path = `/uploads`;
   fs.mkdirsSync(path);
   cb(null,  __dirname + path);
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
   // console.log(file);

 cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname.replace(/\s+/g, "-"));
}
})

 var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

 let createUserImage = upload.single('images');


 let multerHelper = {
 createUserImage,

 }

 module.exports = multerHelper;
```

In your `product.js`(route) file import this file

```
  const multerhelper = require("../multerhelper.js");  
  router.post("/new",multerhelper.createUserImage,ProductController.
  create_product);
```

Comment: Sorry for being late. This also doesn't work. Still same error.

Comment: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\\astrology\\jyotish_sanjivni\\server\\api\\middleware\\uploads\\1601722470379OQ58cI.jpg

Comment: comment this code `const directory = path.join(__dirname, "utils/uploads");
app.use("/uploads", express.static(directory));` of  and than try to run

Comment: Still no luck :/

Comment: check i have updated app.js file import files according to your requirements

Comment: Tried. Still not working. Your approach is completely perfect, but nothing seems to work for me :/

Comment: add full app.js code or i have one more solution which will convert image in base64 using multer you can direct upload it on database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222443/discussion-between-bubble-cord-and-arya).

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to resolve this. I am posting the solution if anyone comes across the same issue (Windows OS to be specific), this will surely help.

I changed my directory structure by shifting the `uploads` folder directly outside instead of `/utils/uploads`(for the sake of easeness) & made a minor change in **fileUpload.js**:

```
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, process.cwd() + "/uploads/");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname.replace(/\s+/g, "-"));
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  // reject a file
  if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype === "image/png") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5,
  },
  fileFilter: fileFilter,
});

module.exports = upload;
```

Instead of using `__dirname`, I replaced it with `process.cwd()`, and appended my target folder :

```
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, process.cwd() + "/uploads/");
  },
```

**Reference**: [What's the difference between process.cwd() vs __dirname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874382/whats-the-difference-between-process-cwd-vs-dirname)

P.S. Thanks to @jeeves & @Arya for their thorough suggestions :)