# How to set express static path when app is in dependency module

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express application which is provided from a module which in turn is located in node_modules like this:

```
home
  user
    project
      app.js
      dist
      main.css
      an.svg
      node_modules
        static-webserver
          server.js
          public
            dev
              websocket.js
```

**app.js** invokes the express **static-webserver** like this:

```
require('static-webserver/server.js');
```

In **static-webserver/server.js** I am setting two particular paths. One path, which maps **/dev** to static-websserver's **public/dev** directory maps like this:

```
app.use('/dev/', express.static(__dirname + '/public/dev/'));
```

This path is is working.

But the second path

```
app.get('/dist', express.static(Path.resolve('dist')));
```

is not resolving to the dist directory of the application. **Path.resolve('dist')** should resolve an absolute path **/user/project/dist/** but it does not. It always tries to resolve
to **/home/user/project/node_modules/static-webserver/dist**, which is not what I need.

Is there any way to make express static accept absolute paths?

Answer (score 0):

If the `absolute` path to the `/dist` directory is known, I suggest not using `Path.resolve` and instead using `process.cwd()`, or `__dirname` (in combination) to access `/dist`.

```js
app.get('/dist', express.static(process.cwd() + '/dist'));
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9874415/16471349

Comment: It's not working either. process.cwd() simply returns an absolute path as String. It's the same as when I use path.resolve(). And despite the path pointing to /home/user/project node does seem to confine file access to the static-webserver (the dependency module) location. And the more I think about it, the more it makes sense. Because that would constitute a security problem. That's my take on this. But thanks anyway for your effort.