# Nodejs Index.html Loads but Links & Scripts 404

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have a nodejs server running with the client side encapsulated in a client folder to make managing the folder structure for index.html easy. Then the links and scripts should load no problem.

```
client folder
  /index.html
  /style.css
  /script.js
closer folder
  /closure
  /etc. 
app.js
package.json
utility.js
```

In my app.js file I have a normal

```
app.get ('/', function (req,res) {
res.render('index.html');
});
```

and when I run and go to the local host port the file loads, but when I open the chrome console, I see that the index.html file failed to load any of the scripts with a 404 error not found. I notice that in a lot of express apps there seems to be a common pattern of something along the lines of

```
this app.set('views', __dirname + '/client');

this app.use(express.static(__dirname + "./client"));

this app.use('client', express.directory('client'));
```

but I don't see an explanation on the difference between app.use and app.set, nor a good explanation, the best the I could find was

> app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'): Use ./views as the default
>   path for the client-side templates

from [Alex Young's article](http://dailyjs.com/2012/09/13/express-3-csrf-tutorial/) but even this was a little sparse and dry for me, I'm hoping for a bit deeper of an explanation as to why the index file might be unable to load a link on the same directory level as it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

I look at this and I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 5):

From the answer [Express-js can't GET my static files, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924072/express-js-cant-get-my-static-files-why#answer-5924732) I'd suggest:

```
app.use("/client", express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
```

This is needed because your:

```
app.get ('/', function (req,res) {
res.render('index.html');
});
```

is only addressing what happens when someone goes to `/` and saying that index.html should be served. That alone doesn't serve anything else.

Answer (score -1):

just run your server from root directory of your project.
that will fix the problem because you used relative addressing.