# Can't serve up a static directory using Node 0.9 and latest express 4.11.2

Tags: node.js, express

Using the following simple Node server

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); //  "public" off of current is root
app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

I have of course put a 'public' directory in my root and also dropped a index.html file in it but when i point my browser to

> http://localhost:3000/public/

I get

> Cannot GET /public/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Express-js can't GET my static files, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924072/express-js-cant-get-my-static-files-why)

Answer (score 0):

This one caught me out as well when starting with express.

`http://localhost:3000/public/` won't be accessible.

For example lets say you have a `css` folder inside of the public directory with a file called `styles.css`

Your browser would be able to access that file at `http://localhost:3000/css/styles.css`.

The express documentation on express.static can be found here: [app.use (under the two example tables)](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use)

edit 1: See this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5924732/1286700).

edit 2: @Leonid Beschastny answer is correct, I didn't see that a path to a folder was missing in `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you're mounting `express.static` middleware. In your example you're mounting it to the root of your application.

So, in your example you should be able to access content of `/public` directory from `http://localhost:3000/`.

So, all you need is to specify a mounting point for `express.static` middleware:

```
app.use('public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

You should also keep in mind that `express.static` don't have a default index page. So, if you have no `index.html` in your `public` directory you'll get 404 anyway (`express.static` won't list your files like `apache` do).