# Referencing java script files from html in nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am having a node js server that serves index.html when user hits localhost:3000/

```
app.get('/', function (req, res){
  res.render('index.html');
});
```

However i cant figure out how i can refer to myscript.js javascript file from within the index.html.

```
<script src="script/my_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am calling a click button function from this file, but at run time this call gives 404. Please let me know how i can refer to a javascript file from within index.html in a nodejs server setup.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Express-js can't GET my static files, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924072/express-js-cant-get-my-static-files-why)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up a **static directory** in which express will serve files as-is. For example:

```
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

You can then create a "public" directory in your app root, and move your "script" folder inside. Any files (such as javascript, css) inside will be served directly to clients.

[Docs](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.built-in)