# Issue Routing With Node.js - Cannot GET

Tags: javascript, node.js

I finally got everything working on a certain page, but the issue I'm facing now is when I create additional pages.  I realize the issue must be with my routing, but I'm not sure how to change the server side code without effecting my app.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  // socket functions
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

I would like to serve html in a folder 'public' and have files like index.html and other.html in there.

Comment: So, basically you're asking how to serve static files with Node ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Express-js can't GET my static files, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924072/express-js-cant-get-my-static-files-why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your express app to use a static directory.

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

All files located under public can now be accessed. So a file called index.html can now be reached via `/index.html`

Further documentation can be found here:

http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Ah, great - this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for the link as well.  I  will read more into this.  I changed my code to: var app = require('express')(),
 http = require('http').Server(app),
 io = require('socket.io')(http),
 express = require('express');

app.use(express.static('public'));

Answer (score -2):

If your folder is called `public` then you could do something like

```
app.use(express.static('./public'))
    .get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile('index.html', {root: 'public/'});
    })
```

Comment: This returns "ReferenceError: Express is not defined" when I try to start the server

Comment: That's because it is indeed not defined. Have a global like ```var express = require('express')``` and it will work

Comment: Ah, okay - thanks.  Late night, lots of learning, brain is fried.