# some static files not found in express

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, static

I have the following node server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.render('pages/index');
});

app.get('/abstract', function(request, response) {
    response.render('pages/abstract');
});

app.get('/PCA', function(request, response) {
    response.render('pages/PCA');
});
...
```

Below are my files where app.js is:

- views

  - pages

    - index.ejs
    - abstract.ejs, etc.
  - partials

    - header.ejs
    - nav.ejs
- public

  - css

    - main.css
  - img

    - logo.png
    - linear.png

After pushing to heroku, images on the "/" route are rendered. However, on '/abstract' '/PCA', only the images in the nav.ejs are showing up and all other images are not found. My css static file is found on all files. I've tried without success:

```
<img src="linear.png" id="linear"/>
<img src="img/linear.png" id="linear"/>
<img src="/img/linear.png" id="linear"/>
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Is that third `src` tag a typo (it should be `/img/linear.png` instead of `/imglinear.png`) or did you really try that?

Comment: sorry that was a typo

Comment: @mscdex I'm not sure why only images on the "/" directory is rendering, so I think it might have to do with how I'm routing the app. I am new to express, but I've followed many examples like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924072/express-js-cant-get-my-static-files-why

Comment: do the images show up when you are working on the application locally?

Comment: yup perfectly fine... I can't really explain why. When I git push heroku master, the sourced are pushed.