# external Javascript and CSS are not effected to HTML when the HTML is invoked by Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I created a simple `Node JS` program. I have `index.html` in the same folder that `app.js`is located and external `css` and `js` files within `public/stylesheets/style.css` and `/public/javascripts/script.js` directories. When i open the  `index.html` directly form the browser, `css` file is syccessfully linked to the `html` file. But when i run `node app.js` and navigate to `http://localhost:3000`, the `index.html` is displayed but any style didn't have effected to it. How can i solve it?

`app.js` file is this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

`index.html` file is this

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sanitizor</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="public/javascripts/script.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/stylesheets/style.css">

</head>
<body>
<h3>hello</h3>
    <div id="chat"></div>
    <form id="sent-message">
        <input size="35" id="message"></input>
        <input type="submit"></input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you write, in address bar, the full server path `http://localhost:3000/public/stylesheets/style.css` you should get your CSS, if not, path is incorrect.

Comment: You have to enable static serving of your resource files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express-js can't GET my static files, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924072/express-js-cant-get-my-static-files-why)

Comment: "static serving" I'm not sure what that is.Tried both Answers in that question. non of them works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable static serving :

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); //this line enables the static serving in the public directory
```

your `public` directory could be the following :

```
public 
|_css
|_js
|_images
  |_logo.png
```

Then, if you want to get an image :

```
http://localhost:3000/images/logo.png
```

And if you want to show it in your html page :

```
<img id="logo" src="/images/logo.png"/>
```

In your case, replace the following line

```
<script src="public/javascripts/script.js"></script>
```

by

```
<script src="/javascripts/script.js"></script>
```

Same goes with the css

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working. Saved me from a lot of mess!

Answer (score 0):

Like Cristy already stated in her comment, you need to enable static serving of your resource files. In order to do so you use [express.static](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). Express has good [documentation](http://expressjs.com/) and guides about routing or middleware etc, so check it out.

Consider a file structure like:

```
/app
   /public/index.html
      /stylesheets/style.css          
      /javascripts/script.js
```

Your app folder contains the `app.js` and the rest is ordered like discribed.

Your `app.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

Most of the time the order is important so you need to be carefull. In order to configure express you can use `app.configure(function() {...});` and put all you `app.use(...)` commands in there.

Your index.html now should look like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sanitizor</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/script.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/style.css">

</head>
<body>
<h3>hello</h3>
    <div id="chat"></div>
    <form id="sent-message">
        <input size="35" id="message"></input>
        <input type="submit"></input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```