# __dirname is not working in node js with webpack bundling

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack

My current directory is

```
D:\bkp\Programming\TestWorks\nodejs\testApp
```

but when i am using `__dirname` and trying to show a file with express server it gives me this error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\views\index.html'
```

my code for that is

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + 'views/index.html');
```

when i am bundling it with webpack and run the bundle file then this happens. Otherwise if i just run the normal app.js file it works fine. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is because webpack can handle __dirname (and other node specific things) in different ways. If you want it to behave like normal, use this in your webpack config:

```
{
    node: {
        __dirname: false
    }
}
```

See: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/

Comment: Some of the google client libs are requiring dirname to be set to true in webpack.config. But for reading mail templates from the file system, i would like dirname to be the output dir. Is there a way to set it only for some node modules? My cur workaround is using process.cwd() and then /dist for the output dir. But i do not really like that

Answer (score 12):

The `__dirname` is set to `/` by webpack, that's why you end up with `/views/index.html` which is the root of your file system, that happens to be `D:\` in your case. You can set `node.dirname` to `false` in your webpack config to not inject it and defer it to runtime. Keep in mind that `__dirname` will refer to the location of the script you're executing, that means the location of the bundle, not the original source.

```
node: {
  __dirname: false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`"webpack": "^5.24.4"`
the default value depends on the `target` configuration property:

`target: 'web'` => `__dirname = '/'`

`target: 'node'` => `__dirname = 'the full path of the output directory'`

It can be adjusted using `node` configuration property, see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#node__dirname

Comment: That shoul be marked as the best answer IMO (at least for webpack 5)