# Serving static javascript files with Node.js, Socket.IO and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have a simple node.js application which uses socket.io and express. At the moment all of the javascript is in the HTML file but I would like to try and separate it out into a .js file.

In my main node application I have this:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

This works fine until I move my javascript from index.html to a .js file then try to reference it from my HTML file like this:

```
<script src="functions.js"></script>
```

I think that express is not serving the static file so I have tried this:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/functions.js');
});
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How about reading the docs? [Serving static files in Express](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: [Express-js can't GET my static files, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924072/express-js-cant-get-my-static-files-why)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nodejs and express do not serve ANY files by default.  So, when you created your first route:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

That successfully allowed a browser request for `/` to see your index.html file.  The browser will then receive that HTML file and parse it.  If it finds `<script>` tags inside that file, it will then make a new web request to your server.  So, if that file has this in it:

```
 <script src="functions.js"></script>
```

The browser, will then ask your server for `/functions.js`.  Since you had no route for that request, your server will return a 404 error and the browser will not get your script file.

So, you have to make a route that will properly serve `/functions.js` when the browser asked for it, while still keeping your existing route that serves the index.html file.

You can either make a specific route for `/functions.js` just like you did for `/`.  Or, for static files, you can use `express.static()` to create a smart route that can serve many static files.

To use `express.static()` you create a directory on your server (it can be anywhere), but folks often put it below the directory where your server files are.  I generally choose to name it `public` so it's obvious to everyone that these files are publicly available.  Then, you can create a smart route using express.static like this:

```
app.use(express.static("/js", path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

This line of middleware tells express that if any requests come in that start with `/js`, then look for a matching file in the `__dirname + "/public"` directory.  So, if a request comes in for `/js/functions.js`, then look for a file named `__dirname + "/public/functions.js"`.  If that file is found, then serve it automatically.  To make this work properly in your index.html file, you would make the `<script>` tag be this:

```
 <script src="/js/functions.js"></script>
```

The `/js/` prefix I've used here is purely up to you.  You don't even have to use a prefix and it can be named anything you want.  You just have to make sure that the prefix you use in the `<script>` tag matches the prefix you use in the first argument passed to `express.static()`.  I like to use a prefix for my static JS and CSS files so they are stored and looked for in a location that is different than my core HTML files (that's just a personal preference of mine, but down the road it might also make caching simpler or make using something like NGINX to improve performance simpler too).

---

To use `express.static()` you have to save a reference to the `express` module by changing this:

```
var app = require('express')();
```

to this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

Or, in any recent version of nodejs, I prefer to use `const` for variables that should not be reassigned:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

Comment: Why the downvote for this answer?  What is wrong about this answer?

Comment: Thanks this is a great help but I receive this:

    'ReferenceError: express is not defined'

Comment: @Tim - See what I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: @jfiend00 - Thanks thats got it! Appreciate the help.

Comment: This did not work for me, it should be in the form `app.use("/js", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));`

Comment: @TomC. - Your code works with a different URL and directory structure.  So, you have to use the code that works with your chosen layout and URL design.  So, it's a matter of setting Express up to match how you're doing things.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple: utilise `express.static` built-in middleware function in express.

For example, you can add this into your main node application:

`app.use("/js", static(__dirname + '/js'));`

For more details, read this: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html