# Node refused to apply style because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME

Tags: html, css, node.js

I am going to server an static `index.html` with `main.css` using this node server:

The serve.js :

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
var path = require('path');

app.use(cors())

app.use(express.static('assets'))

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 3000')
})
```

The **index.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/main.css">

    </head>
    <body>

        <p>Hello Html!</p>
        <div class="thejson"></div>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**main.css**

```
body {
  background: #ffdd;
  color: #eaeaea;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

The structure:

```
project structure:
       index.html
       serve.js
       assets
             js
             css
                main.css
```

When I load `index.html` the css is loaded, but serving it fron node, I get:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/css/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

I've also tried `href="/assets/css/main.css"` and `href="./assets/css/main.css"` with no avail.

What could be wrong here? How can I fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924072/express-js-cant-get-my-static-files-why

Comment: @zer00ne not sure how that answer applies to my case but changing the css file name to `default.css` did not work.

Comment: You should read it, Codisan obviously did.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

replace this line

```
app.use(express.static('assets'))
```

with

```
app.use('/assets', express.static('assets'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the very same problem, and running through the trouble for almost hours, I noticed that I had to use this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname, "../public"));
```

It should do the job and hopefully, save your time.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem recently. I had index.html in the folder '/public' as well as index.ejs in /views. It'd misled Node.js, so I deleted index.html as well as other html pages from the /public folder. Hopefully, it will save your time

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'))
```

use this it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the particular folder you are trying to serve your static files.

```
app.use('/assets', express.static('assets'))
```