# How can I link my CSS styles without getting MIME error

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I have a Nodejs - Express - Vanillajs project and when I tested my routes the index page doesn't load CSS and have this error:

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/public/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

in the browser console. I tried it with Chrome, Chromium and Firefox as well. My folder structure is:

```
server.js
public
|-css
  |style.css
```

I'm using MVC architecture and my view engine is index.html
CSS is linked with

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/css/style.css" />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201869/node-refused-to-apply-style-because-its-mime-type-text-html-is-not-a-support

Answer (score 0):

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/public/css/**bootstrap.min.css**' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

This error is talking about bootstrap. I think that error occurs when the file isn't found. The link returns some 404 error in html->MIME type ('text/html').

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my routing

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));`

And I had to add a slash

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`