# The CSS code is not showing up on my node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was trying to use a CSS file in my node.js server, but it never show up on the webpage. I'm doing this on Visual Studio Code 2019.

```
'use strict';
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var fs = require("fs");
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
    fs.readFile("index.html", function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
            res.writeHead(404)
            res.write("Error: File Not Found")
        }
        else {
            app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));
            res.write(data)
        }
        res.end();
    })
}).listen(port);
```

And on my HTML file I did:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">
```

The webpage only shows my HTML, but it pretended my CSS code never existed, so it's just a bunch of plain text. I'm still relatively new to node.js so I might just be missing a few simple things.

Directory:

- public (folder)

  - main.css
- index.html
- server.js

Comment: Probably should put `index.html` in your `public` folder, then you can just do `var express = require("express");
var app = express(); 
var path = require("path");
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));
app.listen(port);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express-js can't GET my static files, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924072/express-js-cant-get-my-static-files-why)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That doesn't seem to work, still a plain text webpage. Thanks for helping out though.

Comment: @Thunderous have you restarted the server since you edited the code? The server will continue using the old source until it's stopped and restarted.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yeah I restart the server every time when I make an edit to the code.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I've also noticed something weird when I used the "inspect" on my webpage. I checked the source and when I looked in the main.css file, the content inside is the exact same as the index.html. Not sure if this information would help.

Comment: @Thunderous [edit] your question with your current attempt. Maybe you have an error somewhere else in your HTML file or CSS file? It's basically a guessing game on our part unless you provide a [mcve]. **edit** ah, now that's useful information.

Comment: @Thunderous not sure if it was clear, but the code I provided above was intended to replace your entire `server.js` file.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Woah that actually worked! Thank you! This took me 3 hours and it could've been longer without you! How do I post your response as an answer?

Comment: If you give me a few minutes I can add an answer with a short explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically when you use express, you don't need to use the http module directly yourself. `app.use()` calls shouldn't be placed inside a callback function that is invoked for every HTTP request the server receives, they should be placed somewhere that is run once when the server starts up, like at the top level of your module.

If you move the `index.html` file into your `public` folder, your `server.js` source should be as simple as this:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));

app.listen(port);
```

If you're just trying to run a completely static file server, there's something even simpler you can do. Install `serve` globally and run it on the directory you want to serve files from:

```
npm i -g server
npx serve public -p 1337
```